# Asp Net 1.1 - Issue Accessing Asp DropDownList with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a bunch of dropdownlists that are filled dynamically with Jquery but i'm trying to convert them to Asp:DropDownLists instead of actual pure HTML select dropdowns so i can access and manipulate their values directly from the server side more easily (so i can save the Session value) instead of having to use the Request.Form command. Since the Asp:DropDownList class has it's particularities, i had to adapt the code i had including the Javascript/Jquery functions which access the drops and fill them (all of their ids share a similar nomenclature but with a different number at the end). However, when i try to access the ID, this doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#<%= select_plan_'+i+'.ClientID %>')
```

I always seem to get this compilation error:

> CS1026: ) expected

The "i" has to be there since i'm using a "for" loop to go through all of the drops and fill them. Like i mentioned, all of the drops's ids share a similar nomenclature but with a different number at the end.

This is how one of the drops is defined:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat=server id="select_plan_4" onchange=ChangePrice(this,4);SetSelectedText(4); name=select_plan_4>
...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Anyway, how can i get over this issue? Is there a better alternative? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Js function code added.

```
function ChangePlan(n, control) {

                family = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).split('=')[1];
                $('#select_plan_'+n).find('option').remove().end();
                for (var i = 1; i < data.length-1; i++) {
                    var aux = data[i].split(';');
                    if (aux[0] == family) {
                        var html='<asp:ListItem Value="'+aux[control]+'" Text="'+aux[1]+'" >'+ aux[1] +'</asp:ListItem>';
                        $('#select_plan_'+n).append(html);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: why are you using %= and ClientID?Since id="select_plan_4"..why cant you use direct id selector $('#select_plan_'+i+'4').

Comment: I tried using $('#select_plan_'+i) instead but it only worked when i had the "select" html drops.

Comment: I don't think that'll work, @HameedSyed, because in WebForms the actual HTML controls, when rendered, are given dynamically-generated IDs by the compiler. The ID you can see in the OP's code is the server-side ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the rendered HTML of your page in the Dev Tools for your browser (e.g. by pressing F12 when using Chrome). You'll see that usually the controls, when they're actually rendered, don't have the IDs you've assigned them.

You need to find the actual ID of the rendered control. For a good description of a few techniques for doing this, check out [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery).

Comment: I reverted to  $('#select_plan_'+i)  and checked the markup for the dropdowns. Then i noticed it's displayed as an html select drop instead of an asp:DropDownList. And the id is the same that was defined. The generated dropdown options (shown as "Asp:ListItems" since "option" is not compatible with this dropdown format) are also contained inside the markup but none of them are displayed on the actual page.

Comment: Your WebForms controls will always be rendered as HTML controls - they have to be, a web browser wouldn't know how to display them as WebForms controls, so when your compile your web page they get converted to proper HTML controls. If your IDs aren't changing then I'm guessing your controls aren't inside any other WebForms containers, which makes life easier. Is it working now, then?

Comment: Like i said, the generated options are shown in the markup using the Source option from the Dev Tools (meaning that the Javascript/Jquery function which fills the dropdowns is working) but the page itself doesn't seem to render these options. I'll update the original post with the code for the function.

Comment: Wait, now it works. I just switched the "Asp:ListItem" in the "var html" to option. Anyway, appreciate the help guys!